# Android Signed and Unsigned Export Error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an developed an android app with minimum API level 9 and Maximum 4.4 Kitkat. When i intent to export the app i tried both of the options provided in Eclipse ADT bundle.I tried the unsigned export it compiled and gave a APK file. I copied the APK file to the SD card  and tried to install on my device it said application did not installed..I can't figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is caused by different signatures. Try installing it from console, so you can see deatiled error message.

Answer (score 0):

Un-install your app from your phone first, then try.

You cannot install the built app (APK) if you have the debug (Eclipse) version on your phone.

The package names etc conflict, while it thinks the apps are different, due to the test/release signatures so will not let you install it again.